# Updating multiple tables using .NET and Access

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

Really sorry if this has been asked 10000 times but i couldn't find anything about it.

I'm making backup copies of database tables from a dev site to a live site and i am using this code to do so but i have another 10 tables to copy over and I'm sure there must be an easier way that this?

```
Dim AccessConn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("../../_db/db.mdb") & "")
AccessConn.Open()
Dim AccessCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("DELETE * FROM news", AccessConn)
AccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim AccessCommand2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO news SELECT * FROM news_dev WHERE isapproved", AccessConn)
AccessCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
Response.Write("News Updated")
Response.Write("<br />")

Dim AccessCommand3 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("DELETE * FROM pages", AccessConn)
AccessCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim AccessCommand4 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO pages SELECT * FROM pages_dev WHERE isapproved", AccessConn)
AccessCommand4.ExecuteNonQuery()
Response.Write("Pages Updated")
Response.Write("<br />")

AccessConn.Close()
```

Comment: sorry it was put there by mistake

Comment: Is this a one-time job, or do you expect this to be a recurring task?

Comment: a recurring task mate.

basically they have a dev site that they make updates too but they only want to put approved records on the live site hence the "isapproved"